# Flutter: How to use RefreshIndicator with SliverAppBar

Tags: android, ios, dart, flutter

I'm trying to add `RefreshIndicator` to `CustomScrollView`. Is it possible to do? Here is the code sample:

```
CustomScrollView(
  slivers: <Widget>[
    SliverAppBar(
      title: Text('POSTAPP'),
      centerTitle: true,
      floating: true,
      pinned: false,
    ),
    SliverList(
        delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
          _createPostItem,
          childCount: postRepo.posts.length,
      ),
    ),
  ],
);
```

Comment: Did you try to just place your `CustomScrollView` within `RefreshIndicator`?

Comment: Yes, but in that case the refresh indicator will wrap whole content, including app bar and list view , I want to position it between appBar and listview

Comment: i am facing the same issue, were you able to find a workaround for this case?
I can't use NestedScrollView with my current setup.

Comment: Check Andrey Turkovsky's answer 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52518878/8153664

Comment: Facing the same issue. I don't want to update SliverAppBar.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you're not necessarily restricted to use `CustomScrollView`, you could achieve what you ask for with `NestedScrollView`:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return NestedScrollView(
    headerSliverBuilder: (context, innerBoxScrolled) => [
          SliverAppBar(
            title: Text('POSTAPP'),
            centerTitle: true,
            floating: true,
            pinned: false,
          ),
        ],
    body: RefreshIndicator(
      onRefresh: _loadMorePosts,
      child: ListView.builder(
        itemBuilder: _createPostItem,
        itemCount: _postsCount,
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: I tried this and it seems to prevent app bar show/hide on scroll behavior. What might cause that to happen?

Comment: @SacWebDeveloper experiencing same issue, but only with an 'expandable' SliverAppBar (one that has `FlexibleSpaceBar()` inside).

Comment: Doesn't work correctly with SliverAppBar with flexibleSpace. body remains scrollable even if it is empty

Answer (score 27):

Only like this:

```
RefreshIndicator(child: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: <Widget>[
          SliverAppBar(
            title: Text('POSTAPP'),
            centerTitle: true,
            floating: true,
            pinned: false,
          ),
          SliverList(
              delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(_createPostItem,
                  childCount: postRepo.posts.length))
        ],
      ), onRefresh: () => Future.value(true));
```

SliverList isn't scrollable, so you can't wrap it in RefreshIndicator

Comment: Is there any option to position RefreshIndicator between SliverAppBar and SliverList ?

Comment: RefreshIndicator(displacement: ...) - by default displacement = 40.0. You can set it the same as expandedHeight of SliverAppBar and it'll be shown exactly below appbar. P.S. But it'll slide from up to down through appbar

Comment: I need to make it comes out under the app bar

Comment: Afraid you can't

Comment: @RobertApikyan
You can try using CupertinoSliverRefreshControl() and modifying its build method to display your custom refreshIndicator as needed. Happy Coding  Example:https://gist.github.com/RabiRoshan/6ac289c26c2c726b145a69fa521e3c3d

Answer (score 6):

For anyone circling back to this question, I have found a solution that works using the package [pull_to_refresh](https://pub.dev/packages/pull_to_refresh).

```
final RefreshController _refreshController = RefreshController();

Future<void> _onRefresh() async {
  await Future<void>.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 1000));
  _refreshController.refreshCompleted();
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return CustomScrollView(
    slivers: [
      SliverAppBar(
        title: Text('Title'),
        centerTitle: true,
        floating: true,
        pinned: false,
      ),
      SliverFillRemaining(
        child: SmartRefresher(
          controller: _refreshController,
          onRefresh: _onRefresh,
          // ListView, CustomScrollView, etc. here
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Container(
                  height: 200,
                  color: Colors.red,
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 200,
                  color: Colors.blue,
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 200,
                  color: Colors.yellow,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  );
}
```

Comment: thank you for your solution. There is just on issue -> You have to use a singlechildscrollview, it doesn't work with a listview, which would be desirable for performance improvements

Comment: @GonçaloGaspar I haven't worked with `Flutter` for a while, but when I originally tested this, it worked with `ListView`. Thanks for update.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `CupertinoSliverRefreshControl` inside the slivers list, you need to apply `physics: BouncingScrollPhysics()` to your `CustomScrollView`.

example:

```
    return Scaffold(
      body: CustomScrollView(
        physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
        slivers: [
          SliverAppBar(),
          CupertinoSliverRefreshControl(
            onRefresh: () => refreshList(),
          ),
          SliverList(delegate: delegate),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

in the example above, it will show `RefreshIndicator` in between the `AppBar` and  the `ListView`.

Answer (score 3):

```
 This is the answer

    RefreshIndicator(
    onRefresh: () async {
      return await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2));
    },
    edgeOffset: 100,   // ANY NUMBER SO THE REFRESH APPEARS ANYWHERE YOU WANT.
    child: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: <Widget>[
            SliverAppBar(
                title: Text('POSTAPP'),
                centerTitle: true,
                floating: true,
                pinned: false,
            ),
            SliverList(
                delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                    _createPostItem,
                    childCount: postRepo.posts.length,
                ),
            ),
        ],
     ),
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do by create a custom widget that folk from flutter/lib/src/material/refresh_indicator.dart. and modify the following code (p.s i only added the variable **initialDisplacement**)

```
double initialDisplacement = 100.0;
return Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    child,
    if (_mode != null) Positioned(
      top: _isIndicatorAtTop ? initialDisplacement : null,
      bottom: !_isIndicatorAtTop ? 0.0 : null,
      left: 0.0,
      right: 0.0,
      child: SizeTransition(
        axisAlignment: _isIndicatorAtTop ? 1.0 : -1.0,
        sizeFactor: _positionFactor, // this is what brings it down
        child: Container(
          padding: _isIndicatorAtTop
            ? EdgeInsets.only(top: widget.displacement)
            : EdgeInsets.only(bottom: widget.displacement),
          alignment: _isIndicatorAtTop
            ? Alignment.topCenter
            : Alignment.bottomCenter,
          child: ScaleTransition(
            scale: _scaleFactor,
            child: AnimatedBuilder(
              animation: _positionController,
              builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
                return RefreshProgressIndicator(
                  semanticsLabel: widget.semanticsLabel ?? MaterialLocalizations.of(context).refreshIndicatorSemanticLabel,
                  semanticsValue: widget.semanticsValue,
                  value: showIndeterminateIndicator ? null : _value.value,
                  valueColor: _valueColor,
                  backgroundColor: widget.backgroundColor,
                  strokeWidth: widget.strokeWidth,
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CupertinoSliverRefreshControl` to put refresh indicator between app bar and the list:

```dart
    CustomScrollView(
      physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
      slivers: [
        const SliverAppBar(
          title: Text("Toolbar Title"),
        ),
        CupertinoSliverRefreshControl(
          onRefresh: () async {
            await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2));
          },
          builder: (
            BuildContext context,
            RefreshIndicatorMode refreshState,
            double pulledExtent,
            double refreshTriggerPullDistance,
            double refreshIndicatorExtent,
          ) {
            // You can also use custom widget/animation for the refresh indicator
            return const Placeholder(fallbackHeight: 10);
          },
        ),
        SliverList(
          delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
            (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return const Placeholder(fallbackHeight: 30);
            },
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
```

Credits to [Rabi Roshan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7724779/rabi-roshan) in his [GitHub Gists](https://gist.github.com/RabiRoshan/6ac289c26c2c726b145a69fa521e3c3d).